# Some of the Stateful Intermediate Operation in Java 8 Stream are still Lazy seeking

Tags: java, java-stream

In Java 8 Stream API, description of an intermediate (Stateless)operation like filter, map and peek is mentioned as Lazy seeking - means it'll process element by elements when Terminal operation demands.

Operation are implemented independently on the elements in the stream, when terminal operation hits.

But when it comes to some of the Intermediate (Stateful ) operation like sort() , distinct() - need to process the entire input before producing a result.

For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream - means completing the operation with all the elements not independently before terminal operation demands.

This trigger me a question ( might be silly or misunderstood the lazy seeking with Eager ) that still these "Stateful Intermediate Operation" are lazy seeking ?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Comment: what do you mean by lazy seeking? these operations are simply lazy, this means they are only executed once a terminal operation is called.

Comment: Yes - until you hit the terminal operation in stream, intermediate operation will not executed.Ex :   Stream.of(1, 2, 3).map(i -> {
      System.out.println(i);
      return i;
  });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream. As a result, under parallel computation, some pipelines containing stateful intermediate operations may require multiple passes on the data or may need to buffer significant data.

This means exactly what it says. Some stateful operations may process the entire input. If you go a few paragraphs up, you'll see the following (emphasis added):

> **Intermediate operations** return a new stream. They **are always lazy**; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. **Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.**

So, *yes*, they're lazy. If you invoke `sort` on a Stream and never invoke a terminal operation, `sort` will *not* actually do work on the Stream. That's what *lazy* means. However, once a terminal operation is invoked on the stream, operations like `sort` will operate on the entire input before producing a result. This makes such operations nasty for parallelization and *short-circuiting* operations that could otherwise get away with 
processing only a fraction of the input before producing a value. To be clear:

- Short-circuiting operations on a Stream may process only a fraction of the input before producing a value.
- Lazy operations on a Stream won't trigger work to be done on the stream, until such time as a terminal operation is called on said Stream.
- Intermediate operations are *always* lazy.